# Pygame: Setting a video mode without showing a display

Tags: python, pygame

Basically I need to use `pygame.Surface.convert_alpha()` before showing a display (a window), but trying to do so raises the following exception:

```
     image = image.convert_alpha()
pygame.error: No video mode has been set
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the answer is that you can't.

It's actually kind of pointless anyway, since you can't display a sprite, `convert_alpha`'d or otherwise, unless you set a display first.

What I did is actually the following:

```
def get_sprite(self):
    if not self.converted:
        try:
            self.sprite = self.sprite.convert_alpha()
        except pygame.error:
            pass
        else:
            self.converted = True
    return self.sprite
```

Answer (score 3):

This message might be old but it could help somebody else:
this works fine, in a dirty way :

```
pygame.display.set_mode((1,1), pygame.NOFRAME)
image = pygame.image.load("image.png")
image = image.convert_alpha()
```

Comment: Yes, I actually used that for some time. As you say, it works, but it's dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set video mode:

```
w = 640
h = 480
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
image = image.convert_alpha()
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is exactly what I don't want to do.